# Test dynamic page titles with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I've recently updated my page titles from static text to render dynamic variables from my apps pages. For example:

Static:

```
<% title "Job" %>
```

Dynamic:

```
<% title "Job in #{@job.address.state}" %>
```

My old RSpec test was pretty simple:

```
it 'can see jobs page' do
  expect(page).to have_title('Job')
end
```

My page title helper looks like this:

```
# Page title helper
def title(page_title)
  content_for (:title) { page_title }
end

def yield_or_default(section, default = "")
  content_for?(section) ? content_for(section) : default
end
```

What is the best way to test my dynamic page titles with RSpec? I've tried to use the included matcher to test that the page title string includes `Jobs in` but couldn't get this to work.

Comment: In your rspec, you created a `job` and `address` object right? So why can't you do `expect(page).to have_title("Job in #{job.address.state}")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hard code your expectations. That way, you aren't testing your ability to write the same method chain the same way twice, you are testing what is actually printed on the page a user will see.

```
it 'can see jobs page' do
  expect(page).to have_title('Job in Alaska')
end
```

If for some reason you have not called the methods correctly, this test will break and you'll know exactly what to fix. If that seems hard to do, remember you can use a Factory or set the address state inside your test to whatever you need it to be.